# mysqlclient-1.4.6 now fails to install (Python 3.9) when it did under 3.6

Tags: python, mysql

When I try to use `pip3 install -r requirements.txt` now that my virtualenv (and my host Python version) is somehow 3.9 instead of 3.6 as it used to be, installation of `mysqlclient=1.4.6` now fails this way:

```
Complete output (12 lines):
/bin/sh: mysql_config: command not found
/bin/sh: mariadb_config: command not found
/bin/sh: mysql_config: command not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/private/var/folders/78/m6t5zwl12lz2l9gjd_44x57w0000gn/T/pip-install-6d8h889b/mysqlclient_646d323b983840789a470475ee860b29/setup.py", line 16, in <module>
    metadata, options = get_config()
  File "/private/var/folders/78/m6t5zwl12lz2l9gjd_44x57w0000gn/T/pip-install-6d8h889b/mysqlclient_646d323b983840789a470475ee860b29/setup_posix.py", line 61, in get_config
    libs = mysql_config("libs")
  File "/private/var/folders/78/m6t5zwl12lz2l9gjd_44x57w0000gn/T/pip-install-6d8h889b/mysqlclient_646d323b983840789a470475ee860b29/setup_posix.py", line 29, in mysql_config
    raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (_mysql_config_path,))
OSError: mysql_config not found
```

The `mysql_config` script *does* exist on this system as: `/usr/local/mysql-5.7.16-osx10.11-x86_64/bin/mysql_config` but I don't know how it is supposed to be located by the installer.  And, I don't know why it's failing *now* when it didn't fail *then.*  Please advise.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to have failed while trying to run several mysql related binaries from a python script. Try to set your system's PATH environment to allow the install script to find the mysql related binaries.

```
PATH="/usr/local/mysql-5.7.16-osx10.11-x86_64/bin:$PATH" pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

P.S. I tried to reproduce the installation with the same Python 3.9, mysqlclient 1.4.6 in my Mac environment, and it was installed normally.

```
$ python --version
Python 3.9.4

$ which mysql_config
/opt/homebrew/opt/mysql@5.7/bin/mysql_config

$ python3 -m venv .venv
$ . .venv/bin/activate
$ pip install mysqlclient==1.4.6
Collecting mysqlclient==1.4.6
  Downloading mysqlclient-1.4.6.tar.gz (85 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 85 kB 1.8 MB/s
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for mysqlclient, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: mysqlclient
    Running setup.py install for mysqlclient ... done
Successfully installed mysqlclient-1.4.6
```

Comment: Yep!  That turned out to be the trick!  *(P.S. On my computer I didn't use `brew` ... just MySQL's regular OS/X installer, which also works just fine.)*  The `pip` command couldn't find the script because it wasn't in `$PATH` at the time.

Comment: ***FYI for future readers of this thread:*** Observe that youngminz's response put the `PATH=` command *on* the command-line whereas I used a separate `export` command.  The outcome is functionally the same, the irrelevant-in-this-case difference being that `export` is persistent for the duration of the current session (but not future ones).

Comment: Work for me, after I installed MySQL client and export the "PATH", pip installed successfully. It looked like python3.9 would invoke mysql binaries to do something.

Answer (score 0):

I found my own answer!

In this case:

`export PATH=/usr/local/mysql-5.7.6-0sx10.11-x86_64/bin:$PATH`

*(This being the directory where I separately discovered that the `mysql_config` script is installed on my computer – see above.)* The problem was that the file wasn't in the `$PATH`.  The above command adds it to the beginning of the path list for the duration of the present terminal session.

... then repeat the `pip3 install` command as above, and now it works.